# Problem with my click element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, hubspot-api

I can't make an alert in JS when clicking on the "Submit" button. It's html loaded remotely by a script and the JS can't recognize it.

Here is a reconstruction, anyone have an idea please? http://jsfiddle.net/sdrvqjxn/1/

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js-eu1.hsforms.net/forms/embed/v2.js"></script>
<script>
  hbspt.forms.create({
    region: "eu1",
    portalId: "26927362",
    formId: "46123717-093e-4314-9afb-d71fc6e2e40f"
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What's the issue? You're not calling `alert` anywhere.

Comment: it didn't work so i removed it, it looks like the form is loaded remotely, the elements are not taken into account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `onFormSubmit` option:

```js
hbspt.forms.create({
    region: "eu1",
    portalId: "26927362",
    formId: "46123717-093e-4314-9afb-d71fc6e2e40f",
    onFormSubmit() {
        alert('submit');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. do you know if in the same way I can alert the content of a form field? thanks in advance